# Index Fragmentation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, plsql

I have a table and it includes JSON (Datatype - CLOB) column. Domain index has been created on this column.  LOCAL Partition has been created on this table. We are optimizing this index everyday in the late night and we are gathering stats as well on this table.

So now, when I'm checking on the index fragmentation(by using ctx_report.index_stats pkg) after every load(normally 1200 rows), it is taking 8-10 min to load the data and fragmentation is starting from 30% and then after another load of 1200 rows it would go to 39% and then 45% and it goes on increasing.

Is there any other way to reduce this index fragmentation. Other than optimizing the index and gathering the stats everyday which I'm already doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  As this question is more of a DBA question than a programming question, it would be better asked at https://dba.stachexchange.com.

Comment: I think you should set a daily (at low peak time) job to rebuild index then gather database statistics.